# Is there a way to automatically scroll to the bottom of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

So I'm currently working on a project that has a button that adds cells to a UICollectionView and then needs to automatically scroll to the last cell (i.e. the bottom of the UICollectionView).

I've found the method
`scrollToItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`

But now I'm getting stuck at trying to find the `indexPath` of the last object in the CollectionView.

The problem seems to lie in that I've been trying to think of the cells in the UICollectionView as an array (can't enumerate through them, doesn't respond to `lastObject` and so on). The closest I can seem to get is the method `visibleItems` which *does* give me an array but doesn't help when I need cells that are added outside of the visible frame.

Is there a way to get the IndexPath for that last object in the CollectionView?

Comment: What is your data source? How about getting the count of the data source to determine the last index path?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just ask your data source:

```
NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:self.collectionView] - 1;
NSInteger item = [self collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you! I think I kept overlooking the `section` part of the indexPath so that it kept looking like [15] rather than the [0, 15] that this gives me.

Comment: Also note that scroll position `UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom` will scroll until the cell is just visible. If you want to scroll all the way to the bottom of the collection view, including the bottom section inset, use `UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer... If you **don't** want to ask datasource.

Add it in your `viewDidAppear:` method.

```
NSInteger section = [_collectionView numberOfSections] - 1 ;
NSInteger item = [_collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1 ;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section] ;
[_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 & 4**, assuming you only have one section :

```
func scrollToBottom() {
    let section = 0
    let item = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 1
    let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: I guess you can avoid the extra 2 variables lastIndex path and item, and directly create the indexpath in the scrollToItem method

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue where I could scroll to the ***last*** item in the collection view, but was unable to scroll to the bottom of the ***footer***.

The following code fixed that issue:

```
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, 
                           y: collectionView.frame.height + (collectionView.contentSize.height * CGFloat(itemsInCollectionView.count)))
collectionView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check first if theres is an option to scroll to bottom just in case something goes wrong with your data and your table/collection view doesn't have rows.

```
func scrollToBottomIfPossible() {

    guard self.myRows.count > 0 else {
            return
    }

    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: yourItems.count - 1, section: mySections.count), at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```