# CollectionView Should scroll to last cell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using collection view to showing the taken images of my app.I want as soon as the image taken the collection view should automatically move to last object in my collection view .My collection scrolls horizontally 
Please help me to do this.

I have searched in google and i have found [i have applied this code in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955783/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-uicollectionview)

i have applied this code in my project in viewwillappear ,it showing error,
Please help me to do this

[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5W5P.jpg) i am taking photo and showing in below ,ok ,in this image it has 3pictures ,if i again take a picture 4th picture will be there in collection view ,if user want to se the 4th picture means ,user want scroll by manually and can see it...

Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [session startRunning];
    NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:self.collection_View] - 1;
    NSInteger item = [self collectionView:self.collection_View numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
}
```

I want automatically scroll to the last pictures in horizontally
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: show what you have tried for ?

Comment: Please anyone helpme to do this ,

Comment: i cant get your ques properly.

Comment: @Vaibhav , as soon as user takes a picture , i am showing the taken pictures in same page below the screen in thumbnail using collection view,now i want to scroll automatically to last cell

Comment: okay, from where you getting picture ?

Comment: as i have seen your given link the code looking perfect, show you code how you doing.

Comment: @Saraswathi you can call  [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom) animated:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line inside your `viewWillAppear` method code:

```
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Use this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [session startRunning];
    NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:self.collection_View] - 1;
    NSInteger item = [self collectionView:self.collection_View numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];

    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: [self.collection_View scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

Comment: if i use this ,[self.collection_View scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];  it is showing error like Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACESS .i want to scroll horizontally only , i have tested with horizontal option also,same error only coming

Comment: then it will have some more method like `UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom`, `UICollectionViewScrollPositionUp` and some more just check, bad access error occur because not to implement `collectionView` properly check this also.

Comment: Thanks ,vaibhav ,what i did was ,it should not in view will appear ,i should be in after reloading the collection view ,because at first my collection view will be empty ,

Comment: ohh i see, anyway finally you got :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Swift 4.2 version of the accepted answer

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let section = numberOfSections(in: collectionView) - 1
    let item = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 1
    let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: jumps to a white space

Comment: @OmarNShamali you should post your code setup as a question